# Evosuite 1.0.3 Class 'TestClass_ESTest.class' should be in target project, but could not be found

Tags: java, classloader, evosuite

I have been working on a web application that generates tests, given uploaded Java files and also tests uploaded code against said generated tests. I have been using Evosuite to generate the tests without a problem. However I have just updated to the latest release (1.0.3) and I am now getting the following error when running the generated tests:

```
initializationError(PackOfCrisps_ESTest)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class 'PackOfCrisps_ESTest.class' should be in target project, but could not be found!
at org.evosuite.runtime.instrumentation.EvoClassLoader.instrumentClass(EvoClassLoader.java:125)
at org.evosuite.runtime.instrumentation.EvoClassLoader.loadClass(EvoClassLoader.java:91)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.evosuite.runtime.EvoRunner.getFromEvoSuiteClassloader(EvoRunner.java:139)
at org.evosuite.runtime.EvoRunner.getClass(EvoRunner.java:92)
at org.evosuite.runtime.EvoRunner.<init>(EvoRunner.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)
at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:81)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at finalYearProject.assignmentManager.util.Marker.setupEnvironment(Marker.java:142)
at finalYearProject.assignmentManager.util.Marker.runTests(Marker.java:353)
at finalYearProject.assignmentManager.util.Marker.<init>(Marker.java:39)
at finalYearProject.assignmentManager.Submissions.doPost(Submissions.java:150)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

To run the tests I am creating a new classloader that contains the URL to the directory where the files to be tested along with generated tests from Evosuite are placed.

My application was working successfully before I updated Evosuite but I would like to continue using this new version as the additional features are useful for my project. There may have been a subtle change that I am unaware of so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there was a subtle change in 1.0.3, particularly in the EvoRunner class used to run the tests. To do instrumentation, there are 2 methods: with Java Agent, and with custom classloader. Before the default was Java Agent, but now we use the custom classloader (long story...).

I guess there are some side effects with yours "I am creating a new classloader", if that is different from the one used to load the ES code itself.

A quick check is to set to false `separateClassLoader` in:

`@RunWith(EvoRunner.class) @EvoRunnerParameters(mockJVMNonDeterminism = true, useVFS = true, useVNET = true, resetStaticState = true, separateClassLoader = true, useJEE = true)`

if you run ES from command line, you can try the option `-Duse_separate_classloader=false`

Comment: Thanks @arcuri82. I was getting unusual behaviour from Eclipse that seemed to be causing some issues. I have now moved to a different IDE and so far that seems to have fixed the issue. I have another question though. I am running my test through org.junit.runner.JUnitCore. Any 'ThrowsTooManyResourceException' does not get caught and fails. Running the tests though an IDE works OK. I found this post (https://github.com/EvoSuite/evosuite/issues/7) mentioning a fix. Is there a pattern I must follow to allow ES to catch the exception using JUnitCore? Thanks Again